NDEigensystem gives correct eigenvalues but wrong eigenfunctions
I am trying to reproduce Fig2(b) and 2(c) in this paper by solving Eq2 using NDEigensystem.  Eq2 is a coupled ODE given as
$[\partial_x+k]B1(x)+\zeta(x)A1(x)=EA1(x)$
$-[\partial_x-k]A1(x)-\zeta(x)B1(x)=EB1(x)$
The BCs are $A1(\left\vert x\right\vert\rightarrow\infty)=0$  and $B1(\left\vert x\right\vert\rightarrow\infty)=0$
\[Zeta][x_, a_] := 0.125 Tanh[x/a]
Xrange = 200.;
systm[a0_, b0_] := 
 Module[{a = a0, k = b0}, {vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{
      (Derivative[1][B1][x] + k B1[x]) + \[Zeta][x, a] A1[x],
      -(Derivative[1][A1][x] - k A1[x]) - \[Zeta][x, a] B1[x]
     
     , DirichletCondition[{A1[x] == 0, B1[x] == 0}, True]}, {A1[x], 
     B1[x]}, {x, -Xrange, Xrange}, 2, 
    Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1}}}}];
  Return[{vals, funs}]]    

to get the eigenvalues
getb = systm[0.01, 0.1][[1]]    

which gives {-0.1,0.1} as expected. But only one of the eigenfunctions is correct.
Plot[{Evaluate[ funs[[#]][[1]]], Evaluate[ funs[[#]][[2]]], 
    Abs[ConjugateTranspose[funs[[#]]] . funs[[#]]]}, {x, -Xrange/5, 
    Xrange/5}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Blue}, Black}] & /@ Range[2]        


the right Fig above is same as fig2(b) in the paper, but you can see that the left fig above is not correct, it should be like Fig2(c) in the paper. How can we fix this?
These are fig2b,c in the paper which represent the eigenfunctions of the two eigenvalues.

Updat1
If I change Xrange=8000 and MaxCellMeasure -> 500 I get the two solutions qualitatively correct

Updat2
If we change the sign of \[Zeta][x, a] as  -0.125 Tanh[x/a] then we can get fig2c correct but fig2b becomes incorrect.


What do you mean by 'the other one' and how are these related to fig 2b, c?

There are two eigenvalues valuse -0.1 and 0.1. theire eigenfunctions are in fig2b,c. I got the two eigenvalues correctly, but the eigenfunction of -0.1 is not correct.

@user21, I updated the question, hope it is more clear now.

This doesn't answer the question, but note that you don't need to use Return to return the output of a Module; it's not quite the same thing in Mathematica as it is elsewhere.

I changed MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1 to MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01, and it seems to work much better.... well no, it just seems to switch which one works.

You've set DirichletCondition[{A1[x] == 0, B1[x] == 0}, True] i.e. 4 b.c.s for the system, which makes the system overdetermined. Are you sure it's correct? What's the actual boundary condition? Are you trying to approximate e.g. boundary at infinity? Please clarify.

@xzczd, yes the bcs are A1 and B1 must be zero at infinity.

Please add this to the body of question.

@xzczd, please see my update. I also added the BCs.

Is \[Zeta][x_, a_] := 0.125 Tanh[x/a] an approximation for piecewise constant function?

@xzczd, yes. for the case in the question. but we want also to see the effect of $a$(smoothness) later on.

@xzczd, kindly check my 2nd update.
